# Get matched view in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I have pyramid service and code like this:

```
@view_defaults(route_name="result", context=Result, renderer="json")
class ResultView(RESTView):
    """
    Rest view for exercise results
    """

    @view_config(request_method='GET', permission='view', role="owner")
    @view_config(request_method='GET', permission='view', role="admin")
    @view_config(request_method='GET', permission='view', role="gadmin")
    @schema(Result)
    @log("get result")
    def get(self):
        """
        Gets result
        """

        return self.get.__schema__.dictirialize(self.context, prepare_json=True)

......
```

How can i get matched view inside the `ResultView.get`?

Comment: What are you looking for here? The role that was matched?

Comment: No the view config object that matched when function was called. I'm starting to realize i might have to take different approach.

Comment: there is no "view config" object, this feels like an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom view decorator that attaches `view_id` on `request`. This decorator gets called based on which view config gets activated. Here is an example:

```
    @view_config(request_method='GET', role="owner", permission="view", decorator=view_id("owner"))
    @view_config(request_method='GET', role="admin", permission="view", decorator=view_id("admin"))
    @view_config(request_method='GET', permission="view")
    @schema(User, excludes=('password', 'deleted'), key="owner")
    @schema(User, key="admin")
    @log("get user")
    def get(self):
        return self.get.__schema__[self.request.id].dictify(self.context)
```

And the decorator:

```
def view_id(id):
    """
    Pyramid view decorator that remembers the view id and assigns it to request
    """

    def _view_id(view):
        def view_callable(context, request):
            request.id = id
            return view(context, request)

        return view_callable

    return _view_id
```

It gets the job done for me.